# listbox focusing works totally wrong with shortcuts

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, .net-4.5

When I tab into a ListBox control, the first item gets focused. When I have a label and set the target property to the ListBox (as shown in the code below) and then use the dedicated Alt shortcut then it will focus not the first item but the listbox itself (listbox border becomes dotted). What is the best way to avoid this unwanted behavior? Is there a way to disable focusing on the listbox itself and only allow focusing on the items?

Example code:

> ```
>     <Label Content="_Label" Margin="0,10,0,88" Name="MyLabel" Target="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox}" Height="Auto" />
>     <ListBox Width="100" Name="MyListBox" Margin="46,0,639,0" />
> ```

Behavior:

[image]

Comment: `When I have a label and set the target property to the listbox` - What this exactly meant? Can you post code to make it more clear.

Comment: @RohitVats Added example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting Target you explicitly asked focus to move to listBox. In case you want to put it on first listBox item, you have to do it manually.

One way would be to hook **`GotFocus`** event and set focus to next available item using **`TravelRequest`** object which wil put it on first listBox item.

*XAML:*

```
<ListBox Width="100" Name="MyListBox" Margin="46,0,639,0"
         GotFocus="MyListBox_GotFocus"/>
```

*Code behind*:

```
private void MyListBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource == sender)
    {
        TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
        MyListBox.MoveFocus(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, now with the source checking it works as intended. I still think it is strange that Tab somehow skips the listbox control although it is the "next" control and automatically focuses on the items, unlike the shortcut.

Comment: Not sure that how WPF internally handles it. Might be explicitly handling the Tab navigation to put the focus on it's first container i.e. listBoxItem.